# The name 'myNumber' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I'm sure this has a very simple solution but I'm new to C# and I just can't seem to get rid of this error message.

I'm trying to generate a random number between 1 and 100 inclusive in my code.

```
namespace FirstName_A1
{
    class FromTwoDtoOneD
    {
        static void Main1()
        {
            int[,] twoDArray = new int[10,12];
            int[] oneDArray = new int[10*12];

            FillTwoDimArray(twoDArray);
            DisplayTwoDimArray(twoDArray);
            StoreValues(twoDArray, oneDArray);
            DisplayOneDimArray(oneDArray);
        }

        static void FillTwoDimArray(int[,] twoDArray) //method to fill twoD array with random numbers
        {
            Random myRandom = new Random(); //Random class is under System namespace
            myNumber = myRandom.Next(1, 101); //generates number between 1-100 inclusive

            for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<12;b++)
                {
                    twoDArray[a, b] = myNumber;
                }
            }
        }

        static void DisplayTwoDimArray(int[,] twoDArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two-Dimensional Array");

            for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<12;b++)
                {
                    Console.Write(twoDArray[a, b] + " ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static void StoreValues(int[,] twoDArray, int[ ] oneDArray)
        {
            int c = 0;

            for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<12;b++)
                {
                    oneDArray[c] = twoDArray[a, b];

                    c = c + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        static void DisplayOneDimArray(int[] oneDArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("One Dimensional Array");
            for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oneDArray[a]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `myNumber = myRandom.Next(1, 101);` => where you're declared `myNumber`? Putting `var myNumber` or `int myNumber` should solve declaration issue.

Comment: `myNumber` is not even needed - the `Next` random can go directly into the array - it will also actually pick different numbers that way.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared the variable `myNumber` in the `FillTwoDimArray` method.  I'm declaring with `var myNumber = myRandom.Next(...);`

```
    static void FillTwoDimArray(int[,] twoDArray) //method to fill twoD array with random numbers
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random(); //Random class is under System namespace
        var myNumber = myRandom.Next(1, 101); //generates number between 1-100 inclusive

        for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<12;b++)
            {
                twoDArray[a, b] = myNumber;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly. Also worth noting that the method won't fill the array with different numbers unless the call to `myRandom.Next(...)` is moved into the for loop.

Comment: It's also good practice to move `Random myRandom = new Random();` out as a field to eliminate a duplicate random number bug if the method is called multiple times in quick succession.

Comment: Its not a bug its just how the seeding works with the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know these questions probably seem dumb to you guys but I'm still learning.